# Qgis making a backgound map for topolines on Garmin

Tags: qgis, garmin, references

I am a new user of QGIS, I would like to make a background map with Topolines in gmap or img format.

So I started off with Opendem shape files. I have successfully combined the tiles I want into one shapefile. I would like to use them as a background to view behind an OpenStreetMap map, on a Garmin Etrex 20.

Now I just do not know where to go from here.

Do these files need to be converted into raster files or what would be next?

Can someone point me to a good tutorial?

Comment: If you just want to view layers on top of another, you can change the _Layer order_ (View > Panels > Layer order) and play with the ordering. Is this what you mean? I used this website to learn some basics: http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/

Comment: No I mean a want to create a map with topolines that I can load on my Garmin Etrex 20

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the "GarminCustomMap" plugin to create the .kmz file, then copy the .kmz file to the /Garmin/CustomMaps folder on your GPS receiver's microSD card. Create the CustomMaps folder if it doesn't yet exist.

Comment: Does this create a vector map or a raster map?

Comment: It creates a raster map in .kmz format.

Comment: I just tried it out and it is very easy to use. But I found some limitations. It seems like you can only take a screenshot of what is on your computer. I can get a larger area by zooming out a bit, and put a bigger zoom level on the import setting. But then the lines become too thick. So it only works for a very small area much smaller than the limit that is given by Garmin. Is there a way to produce a larger area than your computer screen?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want contour lines from a DEM added to your Openstreetmap vector map.

The best way to do that is using SRTM data with the mkgmap toolchain.

If you hav the contours already as a shapefile, you could use a tool like shp2osm to transfer it into osm format, then create the Garmin img files from that.

QGIS has no supprt for Garmin img vector format.

The Garmin custom raster format .kmz has a strong limitation on the map extent, making it useless for your purpose.

Comment: I see what you mean Kmz also makes the scrolling on the GPS slow. What do you exactly mean with creating an map via osm. Making a map with vector lines only or adding the lines to an existing osm map?